# How to pass variable to external JS file in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, eval

I want to use variable of `default.aspx.cs` in `default.aspx` file in the script and i successfully it like

```
public partial class default: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string _file = string.Empty;
    public string _img = string.Empty;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _file = "~/videos/myVideo.mp4";
        _img = "~/images/myImg.png";
    }
}
```

and in my `default.aspx` file

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="dv_video"></div>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- jw Script -->
<script src="../jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("dv_video").setup({
        file: '<%= _file %>',
        image: '<%= _img %>',
        height: 500,
        width: 850
    });
    </script>
<!-- jw Script -->
```

this code is working fine, I want to shift this script code to external javascript file `extras.js` how can i access `_file`, `_img` variable on that javascipt file thats looks like

```
jwplayer("dv_video").setup({
    file: '<%= _file %>',
    image: '<%= _img %>',
    height: 500,
    width: 850
});
```

**Edited**

I have use this code to pass parameter to the js file `extras.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/jwplayer/extras.js") %>">
    _image: '<%= _img %>';
    _file320: '<%= _file320 %>';
    _file480: '<%= _file480 %>';
</script>
```

and this code to use parameter on js file

```
jwplayer("dv_video").setup({
    image: window._image,
    sources: [{
        file: window._file480,
        label: "480p HD",
        "default": "false"
    },
    {
        file: window._file320,
        label: "360p SD",
        "default": "true"
    }],
    height: 500,
    width: 850
});
```

Answer (score 4):

There's several ways to do that. You can either define a global JS variable like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_file = '<% _file %>';
_image = '<% _image %>';
</script>
```

Then you can use those variables in your external JavaScript file like this:

```
var file = window._file;
var image = window._image;
```

Another solution is to add those variables into your HTML as data values.
Like the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="dv_video" data-file="<% _file %>" data-image="<% _image %>"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you can get those data-values in your JS like this:

```
var image = $('#dv_video').data('image');
var file = $('#dv_video').data('file');
```

Comment: thank for your help, but unfortunately both of these way did't work for me, actually i am new to java script, can you help me furture

Comment: Hi @UsfNoor - I'd like to help you further, but you need to show me which one of them you've tried and show me how they're not working. Can you show me some code? :-)

Comment: I have add code to edited section of the question, that i had use,

Comment: The method you've used should work. I'm doing exactly that in one of my solutions, but if that method won't work for you, try using the other option and do it with data-attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small correction. Use '=' instead of ':' to assign the value to the variables, like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 _file = '<% _file %>';
 _image = '<% _image %>';
</script>
```